# Android disable PageTabStrip

Tags: android

i'm trying to disable tab to switching between tabs and i'm using this below code. but that doesnt work:

```
public class CustomPagerTabStrip extends PagerTabStrip {

    private boolean isTabSwitchEnabled;

    public CustomPagerTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.isTabSwitchEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ENable?? "+isTabSwitchEnabled); // it prints out false or true based on what I have set
        if (this.isTabSwitchEnabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.isTabSwitchEnabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setTabSwitchEnabled(boolean isSwipeEnabled) {
        this.isTabSwitchEnabled = isSwipeEnabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to disable switching between tabs while swiping view pager right?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal i'm disableing viewpager on this TabStript, but click on tab items work and should be disabled

Comment: tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(your_index).setEnabled(false);

Comment: You can always remove OnPageListener from your tabs, and re-attach it later when it should be enabled again

Answer (score 0):

You can through this link [Disable PageTabStrip](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpagertabstrip-fragments-tutorial/)